# Problem with general progressions

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Question:** Let $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$, and $a_5$ be such that $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are in an $A.P.$ and $a_3,a_4,a_5$ are in $H.P.$ Then prove that $\log{a_1},\log{a_3},\log{a_5}$ will be in $A.P.$

**My approach:**
As $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are in an $A.P.$, $$2{a_2}={a_1+a_3}$$
Let's call this equation $I$

And as $a_3,a_4,a_5$ are in $H.P.$, then $$a_4=\frac{2a_3a_5}{a_3+a_5}$$

Let's call this equation $II$

My problem is that after I substitute the value for ${a_3}$ as $2a_2-a_1$ in equation $II$, I do not get the desired answer. Please help.

Comment: You missed the 2 in HM

Comment: Basically you have to prove, $a_3^2=a_1a_5$

Comment: Given $a_1,a_3,a_5$ such that $\log{a_1},\log{a_3},\log{a_5}$ are NOT in A.P. then we can always find $a_2$ and $a_4$ such that the given conditions are satisfied. Are sure that the statement is correct?

Comment: @RobertZ I searched for the question online before posting here and one more statement was mentioned that $a_2,a_3,a_4$ are in $G.P.$. I'm just wondering if the question can be solved without using the above statement.

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20- Thanks, I forgot to write that.

Comment: No, we need that further condition.

Comment: @RobertZ Thanks then

Comment: As a concrete example of what @RobertZ says: Consider $4, 3, 2, 2, 2$ as a counterexample.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [5 numbers in AP, GP and HP.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3165926/5-numbers-in-ap-gp-and-hp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $a_1,a_3,a_5$ such that $\log{a_1},\log{a_3},\log{a_5}$ are NOT in A.P. then we can always find $a_2$ and $a_4$ such that the first two conditions are satisfied. Take, for instance, $a_1=1,a_3=3,a_5=5$ and
$a_2=2$ and $a_3=15/4$.

On the other hand, by considering ALSO the third condition, i.e. $a_2,a_3,a_4$ are in G.P., we have that
$$a_3^2=a_2a_4=\frac{a_1+a_3}{2}\cdot \frac{2a_3a_5}{a_3+a_5}\Leftrightarrow a_3=(a_1+a_3)\cdot \frac{a_5}{a_3+a_5}$$
which implies that
$$0=a_3(a_3+a_5)-(a_1+a_3)a_5=a_3^2-a_1a_5$$
and therefore $\log{a_1},\log{a_3},\log{a_5}$ are in A.P.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG $a_3-a_2=a_2-a_1=d$  and $\dfrac{a_5}{a_4}=\dfrac{a_4}{a_3}=r$

$\implies a_1=a_3-2d, a_5=a_3r^2$

If $\log(a_1),\log(a_3), \log(a_5)$ are in AP

$\iff a_1,a_3,a_5$ in GP

$\iff a_1a_5=a^2_3$

$\iff(a_3-2d)a_3r^2=a^2_3$

$\iff a_3=\dfrac{2dr^2}{r^2-1}$